# Limit the number of processed messages from channel

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I recieve around 200 000 message/seconds over channel to my worker, I need to limit the number of messages I will send to the client to only 20 per second.
This make it 1 message per 50 milliseconds

And the worker will still alive during all the program lifetime with the help of the LOOP (and not opening a channel for each message).

**My goal:**
- Since the order of the messages is important, I want to skip all the messages that comes during that blocked 50ms and save only the latest one
- If the latest one come during the blocked 50ms, I want the saved message to be processed when the block time is over inside the loop and no new message coming ! <-- This is my problem

**My strategy**
- Keep sending the latest message that is not yet processed to the same channel

But the problem with it, what if that message is sent after a new message that comes (from the application) ?

The code below is more an algorythm as a working code, just want a tip/way on how to do it.

```
func example (new_message_from_channel <-chan *message) {
    default = message
    time = now_milliseconds
    diff_accepted = 50milli
    for this_message := range new_message_from_channel {
        if now_millisecond -  time >= diff_accepted {
            send_it_to_the_client
            time = now_milliseconds
        } else {
            //save the latest message
            default = this_message

            //My problem is how to process this latest message when the blocked 50ms is over and no new message coming ?!

            //My strategy - keep sending it to the same channel
            theChannel <- default
        }

    }
}
```

If you got an elegent way to do it, you are welcome to share it with me :)

Comment: Use a rate limiter e.g. https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate

Comment: @colm.anseo I can't see how to integrate that, can you pointe me to an example please ? Thanks !

Comment: Just published an example usage of `golang.org/x/time/rate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a rate-limiter, you can create a `throttle` function which will take: a rate and a channel as input; and return two channels - one which includes all of the original channels items, the other only relaying items at a fixed rate:

```
func throttle(r time.Duration, in <-chan event) (C, tC <-chan event) {

    // "writeable" channels
    var (
        wC  = make(chan event)
        wtC = make(chan event)
    )

    // read-only channels - returned to caller
    C = wC
    tC = wtC

    go func() {
        defer close(wC)
        defer close(wtC)

        rl := rate.NewLimiter(
            rate.Every(r),
            1,
        )

        // relays input channel's items to two channels:
        // (1) gets all writes from original channel
        // (2) only writes at a fixed frequency
        for ev := range in {
            wC <- ev
            if rl.Allow() {
                wtC <- ev
            }
        }
    }()
    return
}
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/upei0TiyzNr

---

**EDIT:**

To avoid using a rate-limiter and instead use a simple `time.Ticker`:

```
tick := time.NewTicker(r)

for ev := range in {
    select {
    case wC <- ev: // write to main
    case <-tick.C:
        wC <- ev  // write to main ...
        wtC <- ev // ... plus throttle channel
    }
}
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/UTRXh72BvRl

Comment: But this will not solve my problem, this will limit the read rate only and will not drop all previous recieved message ! I need all the 200000messages recieved but select only 20 latest one at 50ms for example ... this will only slow down the process and the messages sent to the users are not updated (So we can say it's not did in a real time).

Comment: @cassandra re-read your Q & comment. It sounds like you want a two channel solution: channel #1 streams the original unfiltered messages; channel #2 provides filtered messages - at a rate of 20/s i.e. one ever 50ms. Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: My opinion maybe biased :-) If a ticker meets your needs then go with that - as it doesn't require an external package (although my solution could easily be made to use a ticker). Beyond this, in general I try not to add hidden mechanism where they're not absolutely needed. Adding functionality through layering (e.g middleware handlers and in this case channel filters) - allows this logic to be added or removed with minimal effort or even turned on dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Can you adapte it using a ticker please ?

Comment: I will recheck the code well when I will be free, thank you again for your efforts !